# Dose Apple Merchant Identifier required for payments through Stripe API

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments

I have registered my react-native ios app using the Apple ID identifier on my developer account. I am using stripe to process payments for the items purchased. I have not enabled Apple Pay nor I am planning to. My question is do I still need the get the Merchant Identifier or it will work with Apple ID as I am not enabling Apple Pay on my app. I am new to this this is why I am having understanding the concept.

Comment: Are you selling in-app items or physical items?  For in app items you use in app purchase. Apple handles all of the payment and billing and sends you the funds. You don't need stripe or any merchant set up. If you are selling physical goods or real world services then you can use a payment processor via Stripe. You don't have to support Apple Pay but it is an easier experience for users if you do. You can just collect the credit card details using stripes ios library and send that to your server.  Your server then uses the stripe api to post the payment

Comment: I am selling physical goods. I have sent an appeal to my review and asked them to reconsider.

Comment: If you are selling physical goods then you should not even need to appeal. You cannot use IAP for physical goods. Whether or not you choose to support Apple Pay is up to you, but since you are set up with Stripe and Stripe supports ApplePay, why wouldn't you?  It isn't much more to implement and it is much easier for your users. Note that ApplePay is not in app purchase. You do not pay any money to Apple for ApplePay.

Comment: So do I need the merchant identifier or apple id identifier will work?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native  You need to use your stripe merchant details.

Comment: If you want to accept Apple Pay in your app you do need an Apple Developer account and to get an Apple Merchant ID, and use/configure that in your app along with the Stripe SDK(what paulw is not really accurate, you need both Stripe and Apple details to enable this)